# Flashcards using android

Tags: android

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html

I am using this source code for flipping an image back and forth and it works fine but i want to flip more than one image (i.e one after the other). I have modified first_view by making a horizontal scroll view so i can add more image views. The problem is that after i flip the first image, i am unable to slide to another image and whenever i try to slide to the next image, the first image keeps on flipping back and forth.

I know the issue is really minor but i am unable to figure it out.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Attach your code snippet

Comment: are you using ImageView if so i have a much simpler own built code for you to use.

Comment: yes i am using imageView

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-scale-animation-to-simulate-a-3d-flip/  this is from where i created my FlipAnimation if you dont understand ill post my code its a simple example

Comment: thank you itzik. But does this code work for more than one ImageView ?

Comment: Even the code i am using does flipping well but the problem i am facing is to slide and flip another image. just like any other flash card app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class FlipcardView extends ImageView implements Animation.AnimationListener  {


    private Drawable mBackcardImage;
    private Drawable mCardImage;
    private boolean mCardFlag;
    private Context mContext;

    private Animation mToMiddle;
    private Animation mFromMiddle;

    private FlipAnimationListener mListener;


    public static interface FlipAnimationListener {
        public void onFlipAnimationEnded(boolean isBackcard);
        public void onFlipAnimationStarted();
    }

    public void registerFlipAnimationListener(FlipAnimationListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void unregisterFlipAnimationListener() {
        mListener = null;
    }


    public FlipcardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mContext = context;


        mToMiddle = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.to_middle);
        mFromMiddle = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.from_middle);

        mToMiddle.setAnimationListener(this);
        mFromMiddle.setAnimationListener(this);


    }

    public void StartflipAnimation() {
        this.clearAnimation();
        this.setAnimation(mToMiddle);
        this.startAnimation(mToMiddle);
    }




    public void setBackcardImage(Drawable image) {
        mBackcardImage = image;
    }
    public void setCardImage(Drawable image) {
        mCardImage = image;
    }
    public void setCardImage(Bitmap image) {
        mCardImage = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),image);

    }
    public Drawable getBackCardImage() {
        return mBackcardImage;
    }
    public Drawable getCardImage() {
        return mCardImage;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(animation == mToMiddle) {
            this.setEnabled(false);
            if(!mCardFlag) {
                //Card is Backcard Image 
                setImageDrawable(mCardImage);
            }
            else {
                //Card is Normal Image card
                setImageDrawable(mBackcardImage);
            }
            this.clearAnimation();
            this.setAnimation(mFromMiddle);
            this.startAnimation(mFromMiddle);

        }
        else {
            mCardFlag = !mCardFlag;
            this.setEnabled(true);

            if(mListener != null) {
                mListener.onFlipAnimationEnded(mCardFlag);
            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFlipAnimationStarted();
        }
    }


}
```

dont forget to take the Animation from the link i included to you in the comments 
this class is using Cards but u can use it to anything you need.
since its Extends ImageView every Flip its on its own and not related to any one Camera if you need help with this class just ask its my own code.

Hope it Helps

Comment: @Farazin Yousaf if this helped you please mark is as Answer Thank you.